# JRTPLIB on visual C++ 2008 windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual c++ 2008 ,i need to use JRTLIB for RTP protocol in my project ,
I am a newbie to visual C++ and JRTPLIB.
I need help in including the JRTPLIB to my visual c++ ,i dont know how to include external libraries to visual C++. so anyone please brief me the steps of doing it.
thanks in advance.

with regards,
hari.